# Windows 10, how to recover deleted files that were deleted from a search in the file explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-search, recovery

In Windows 10, I have searched a folder for files containing a certain name and deleted it.

Afterwards, I reconsidered and wanted those files back; I then went looking into the recycle bin, but it was not there.
Is there any way to recover a file that was deleted through the windows explorer search?

Comment: Short answer, no.  You can go to the recycle bin and try to match/recover what you can.  If you held down [SHIFT] during the delete, then no, nothing but file recovery software will help you.

Comment: Then in that case, I will try "Recuva".

Comment: Good luck. If the files have been overwritten, even partially, since then the chances are slim to none.

Comment: The result was it didn't work and it recovered one file out of ~10, which couldn't open either. I guess my best bet is to back up files more regularly in the first place, and be aware that deleting things from Windows Search may actually be irrecoverable, to reduce the risk of loss in the future.

Comment: is this disk an SSD, and Did you try to restore the files in-place on the same disk? SSDs have almost no data recovery capacity, and if you try to restore data to the same disk/partition it was lost from, it's quite possible that recovering the first file destroyed the others you were attempting to restore, so always be sure to restore data to another disk.

Comment: I did restore it to a separate partition, but I'm not sure if it was an SSD. In any case, I will keep in mind the recovery location should be on a completely different disk like an external USB drive.

Comment: We need answer: Is this an SSD, yes/no?

Comment: No, it is not an SSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the responses, I would assume that there are certain "danger zones" in Windows where if you delete a file, it may be **unrecoverable**.
One such danger zone is within the files that show up during a Windows Search from a Windows Explorer.

If there is a need to recover a file, the following ideas need to be followed:

1. Use file recovery software ASAP (i.e.: [Recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva)) since the chances of the files being overwritten increases over time.
2. The recovery location must be different than on the disk / partition in which the file got deleted (i.e.: separate USB stick).

Perhaps the best solution moving forward is prevention, where one (1) simply remembers to never delete files during a Windows Search, and/or (2) back up the particular folder prior to doing any Windows Search on it.